# Slide remaining tr tag up after a tr tag has been deleted using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm implementing delete function using jquery ajax. I'm able to delete the record and remove the `tr` which is represent that record. Now I want to add a little flavor to my code, so I tried to make the `tr` below slide up to replace the position of the deleted `tr` by a jquery like this:

```
 function () {
    tr.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        tr.remove();
    }).promise().done(function () {
        tr.nextAll("tr").slideUp();
 });
```

But the `slideUp` animation doesn't work, all the `tr` below the deleted one just disappear then reappear to replace for the position of the deleted one, please take a look and tell me what have I done wrong. Here's the complete jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("body").on("click", ".waiting", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();        
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforSend: function () { $("#waiting").show(); },
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            data: { "id": $(this).attr("id") },
            success: function () {
                        tr.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                            tr.remove();
                        }).promise().done(function () {
                            tr.nextAll("tr").slideUp();
                     });
            },
            complete: function () { $("#waiting").hide(); }
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are removing will fade out then disappear which will cause a jumpy effect, you should use `slideUp` on the element you remove. It will slide up, disappear, and bring all content underneath it with it.

```
tr.slideUp('slow').remove();
```

Comment: The `slideUp` doesn't work as expected. I wonder is it because I using jquery-1.7.1 or is it because of the behavior of `tr` tag. I'll try replace `tr` with `div` and feedback you asap. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Tried with `div` and with a little optimize, this work like a charm. Thank you very much